# Facebook 810px apps not in center?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm updating my Facebook apps to the new 810px width.

The problem is that Facebook don't seem to center the iframe containing my app.

Here's a screenshot of my 810px app

[image]

Is this only happening to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [New timeline application tab width and logo](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9504867/new-timeline-application-tab-width-and-logo)

Answer (score 0):

No it's happening to me as well.  How did you get the tab to set at 810px.  I was using firebug to test.  Is there a setting i'm missing or is that what you did as well?

Comment: Never mind on the width thing.  I found my answer here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9504867/new-timeline-application-tab-width-and-logo
Still not centered though.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug and is now [fixed](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/179918418787576?browse=search_4f681d191c6137d44583040).